# Application Menu Binding in e4 RCP app for Mac OS

Tags: macos, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

For my RCP app, I am not using any menu. When built for Mac OS, there appears a default menu.

About, Preferences and Quit etc.

How to map default commands to these menu items?

I just want to keep menu for Mac not for other OSs.

In Application.e4xmi,I have created commands for with ids org.eclipse.ui.~ so on.
Should I just need to create HandledMenuItem in Menu contributions? and map the commands with it? Or do I need to add menus for Trimmed Window?

Comment: Is this a 3.x compatibility RCP or an e4 RCP (using an Application.e4xmi)?

Comment: e4 application using Application.e4xmi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to define commands and handlers. The commands must use standard ids known by Eclipse. These are:

- `org.eclipse.ui.file.exit` for 'Quit'
- `org.eclipse.ui.help.aboutAction` for 'About'
- `org.eclipse.ui.window.preferences` for 'Preferences'

Comment: and what if its Eclipse 3.7? I have About and Preferences actions created with ActionFactory.xx.create which works fine everywhere. But in Mac OS special menu those actions don't fire. Any idea if it can work with such old eclipse version at all?

Comment: That is a different question, so ask a new question.

Comment: fair enough, just asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36681543/rcp-application-menus-in-mac-os