# RCP application menus in Mac OS

Tags: macos, eclipse-rcp

I am struggling to figure out how RCP applications on Mac OS work with "About" and "Preferences" actions. I create them with ActionFactory and place them to relevant file menus. Works fine everywhere. However, on Mac OS those actions get placed into application menu by something which knows better where to put other peoples good actions. But of course they don't work.. Any idea why?

(eclipse target platform 3.7, OSX - the latest El Capitan)

Answer (score 1):

For the 3.x style action bar advisor add the menu item in the normal place but use an `ActionContributionItem` and set the menu item in be invisible on the Mac:

So for Quit something like:

```java
IWorkbenchAction quitAction = ActionFactory.QUIT.create(window);
register(quitAction);

ActionContributionItem quitItem = new ActionContributionItem(quitAction);
quitItem.setVisible(!Util.isMac());
menu.add(quitItem);
```

'About' and 'Preferences' can also be specified like this.

`Util` is `org.eclipse.jface.util.Util`.

Eclipse will find these items and move them to the correct place.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it didn't work for me, About and Preferences actions are not responding in application menu (and now they are not visible in my menus as well). I should have mention that Quit action actually works fine and I didn't use ActionContributionItem with it. It exits with keyboard shortcut and mouse click. But there is something wrong with About and Prefs..

Comment: What I showed is the actual code from the Eclipse source.

Comment: May be this needs to be done at a different point of time? I am doing this when ApplicationActionBarAdvisor.fillMenuBar gets called on a startup. Do you know when this "moving to the correct place" actually happening? Can you point me to the actual sources?

Comment: That is exactly where Eclipse does this. In `org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.WorkbenchActionBuilder`

Comment: Yes I see this, meaning that some native cocoa plugin which moves this into mac application menu is not doing this "moving". I am giving up on this, it gets into eclipse versioning voodoo, thank you for the hints!